# Get backup from one folder in a pc in local network to server pc

Tags: c#, network-programming, backup

we have some computers in a local network, that their users create new files or update existing files in a specified folder in these computers. now i want to copy these files in this folder, to a server every 24 hours.

how can I do this in C# ? I want to write a C# program, that do this. and what network configuration i must to do in local computers, so the server can access to the specified folder in local computers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood the question right you can just use a rivision control tool like subversion, or alternatively use tool to Synchronize Folders Between Computers, take a look at [this article](http://lifehacker.com/372175/free-ways-to-synchronize-folders-between-computers).

Comment: can you explain in some details?Thanks

Comment: Please read the article iv just attached, the second idea is good explained there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,it is a good tool, but i want to do this work automatically, with this tool i must to run the "synctoy" app, in local computers, every day(every 24 hours). how can I do this automatically?

Comment: in fact, I want to write a C# program, that copy files from local computers to server